# Is there any way to execute stored procedures in parallel in the same SqlTransaction?

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, parallel-processing

I am wondering if there is a way to execute a few stored procedures in parallel in the same SqlTransaction? SqlTransaction "is not guaranteed to be thread safe" (MSDN). What do you think about it?

Comment: Are you using TransactionScope Class in your C# code?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/af1ee7e0-a851-49f3-9306-faf8235673d2/execute-two-dependent-stored-procedures-using-transaction